# Abort the execution of second Completable if the first fails

Tags: java, rx-java2

I need to execute two methods sequentially, however I need to abort the process if the first method fails.

I've created the following sample to try the `Completable` feature of `RxJava`, but it waits for the end of both methods to go to the `onError` callback.

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        step1().andThen(step2())
        .subscribe(new CompletableObserver() {
            @Override
            public void onSubscribe(Disposable disposable) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onComplete() {
                System.out.println("Completed");
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(Throwable throwable) {
                System.out.println("Error");
            }
        });
    }



    private static Completable step1() {
        System.out.println("Step 1 finished");
        try {
            Thread.sleep(4000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return Completable.error(new Exception());
    }

    private static Completable step2() {
        System.out.println("Step 2 finished");
        return Completable.complete();
    }
}
```

How can I fix this code?

Comment: Your step2 executes before `andThen` takes any effect: as if you wrote `c1 = step1(); c2 = step2(); c3 = c1.andThen(c2);`. Recommended reading: https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava#continuations

Comment: Perhaps use [startWith](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/2.x/javadoc/io/reactivex/Completable.html#startWith-io.reactivex.CompletableSource-) method

Comment: @krokodilko same behaviour. It executes all methods.

Comment: @JulianoNunesSilvaOliveira that because sleep method is blocking the MainThread, the thread which step1 and step2 run on by default

Answer (score 0):

Been able to achieve what I need using `Completable.defer()` (thanks @akarnokd for the suggested link):

```
step1().andThen(Completable.defer(() -> step2()))
        .subscribe(new CompletableObserver() {
            @Override
            public void onSubscribe(Disposable disposable) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onComplete() {
                System.out.println("Completed");
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(Throwable throwable) {
                System.out.println("Error");
            }
        });
```